# Tomcat7 installation in linux

Tags: linux, tomcat

Is it possible to install tomcat7 in linux server when tomcat6 is already presents in the server(i need to install both versions should be available in my server)

Comment: Yes. You will have to make sure they use different ports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy to do. Just download the binary distribution from Apache and install it in whatever folder you desire. Just make sure that your startup scripts use the correct settings for CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE to select the Tomcat to run. You will, of course, have to configure them both to use different ports. If that causes a problem then you can cover it up by using a reverse proxy (NGINX, Pound) to proxy connections to the two different ports and make it appear to be one unified app.